# Use cookies from Post request with a Get Request with Powershell

Tags: powershell, cookies

The issue that I am facing is getting the cookies from a POST request to use be authenticated on the following GET request.

The issue is that despite copying the cookie to the next GET request to be authenticated I am still getting an authentication error. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
$url = "www.example.com/post" 
$postParams = @{user_id='username';user_password='password'}

$webrequest = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -SessionVariable websession -Method Post -Body $postParams
$cookies = $websession.Cookies.GetCookies($url) 

 # Here, you can output all of $cookies, or you can go through them one by one. 

$Nextsession=new-object microsoft.powershell.commands.webrequestsession

foreach ($cookie in $cookies) { 
 # You can get cookie specifics, or just use $cookie 
 # This gets each cookie's name and value 
 Write-Host "$($cookie.name) = $($cookie.value)"


 $Nextcookie=new-object system.net.cookie
 $Nextcookie.name = $cookie.Name
 $Nextcookie.path = $cookie.Path
 $Nextcookie.value = $cookie.Value
 $Nextcookie.domain = $cookie.Domain
 $Nextcookie.expires = $cookie.Expires


 $Nextcookie.comment = $cookie.Comment
 $Nextcookie.commentUri = $cookie.CommentUri
 $Nextcookie.discard = $cookie.Discard
 $Nextcookie.expired = $cookie.Expired

 $Nextcookie.httpOnly = $cookie.HttpOnly
 $Nextcookie.port = $cookie.Port
 $Nextcookie.secure = $cookie.Secure
 $Nextcookie.timeStamp = Get-Date
 $Nextcookie.version = $cookie.Verison


 $Nextsession.cookies.add($cookie)

}


$url = "www.example.com/get"
$Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -websession $Nextsession
Return $Response
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a new cookie called `$NextCookie` but you do nothing with it. I think you want to add `$NextCookie` in the `$Nextsession.cookies.add()` statement and not `$cookie`.

So I believe line 37 of your code should be `$Nextsession.cookies.add($Nextcookie)` not `$Nextsession.cookies.add($cookie)`